# Modalview startup?

Tags: ios, modalviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

I realize this question might sound like a do-it question however I'm not sure how to do this. So my question is, how could I present a sequence of modalviews to show up at the launch of an app for the first time only, like a sequence of welcome pages. I am currently using a storyboard. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What part don't you know how to do? Present a modal view or present a view only the first time the app is run?

Comment: @rmaddy both? can u help?

Answer (score 0):

Use NSUserDefaults to store a variable "presentedIntroView" or something like that. Modally present a view from the root view controller or the first view that opens if that variable is set to false and do not present it if that variable is set to true in NSUserDefaults (which you should set it to once they have gone through the tutorial).  NSUserDefaults will make it so that this information is stored persistently (meaning, from one session to the next).

You can find the NSUserDefaults documentation here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html.  It is essentially a shared, persistent dictionary for your application, and you set the values in it using the methods in the class.